# Appearance of many special characters in my Laravel application after running artisan serve

Tags: laravel

Good day everyone, please I need your assistance, I developed an Application in Laravel 9, up and running fine, after some periods like 9 to 12 months, I re-visited the app, running it again - there appeared so many special characters - both in the console environment and also on the browser.

how can I resolve this?

[image: this is the preview on browser]

I've tried updating every components of the application, but still show the characters

Comment: Please share more details, like any information about the "bugs" you mentioned. Also, how is this problem related to Composer?

Comment: it is an assumption bro, because I've updated my composer too, likewise the Apache server, after I completed the application